# Wicket issue: model of ListMultipleChoice is empty

Tags: java, wicket

Good evening everyone,

I'm currently having a small problem within my Wicket project which is driving me nuts. I tried to break it down extremely in a small example. Actually, they are complex JPA objects with intermediate tables. In addition, there are several address types. I hide all of that for this example.

Goal: all addresses in the database are to be output in a ListChoice (wicket-id: addresses). With a click on the plus button (wicket-id: addToList), all selected entries from the ListChoice should be added to the current SimpleObject. In addition, all addresses assigned to the SimpleObject are displayed in a ListChoice (wicket-id: notifications). If one or more addresses are selected here & then clicked on the minus button (wicket-id: removeFromList), the addresses are removed from the SimpleObject.

Current state: one or more address data records can be selected in the list choice and added by clicking on the plus button. Unfortunately nothing happens when I select a item on the notification-List and click the minus button. When I query within the button's onSubmit method which items have been selected (selectedNotifications), I get an empty list.

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 
<wicket:extend xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
        <form wicket:id="form">
                <label>Available adresses:</label>
                <div class="cronAddresses">
                        <select wicket:id="addresses" class="fullWidth"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons">
                        <input type="button" wicket:id="addToList" value="+" /><br>
                        <input type="button" wicket:id="removeFromList" value="-" />
                </div>
                <label>Included adresses:</label>
                <div class="list">
                        <select wicket:id="notifications"></select>
                </div>
        </form>
</wicket:extend>
```

```
public class SimpleObject implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
        private List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
 
        public List<String> getAddresses() {
                return addresses;
        }
 
        public void addAddress(String address) {
                boolean alreadyPresent = addresses.stream()
                        .anyMatch(curAddress -> curAddress.equals(address));
                if(alreadyPresent == false) {
                        addresses.add(address);
                }
        }
 
        public void removeAddress(String address) {
                List<String> foundAddresses = addresses.stream()
                        .filter(curAddress -> curAddress.equals(address))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                addresses.removeAll(foundAddresses);
        }
}
```

```
public class SimpleTestPanel extends BPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
        private Model<SimpleObject> simpleObjectModel;
 
        private ListModel<String> selectedAddresses = new ListModel<>();
        private ListModel<String> selectedNotifications = new ListModel<>();
       
        public SimpleTestPanel(String id) {
                super(id);
               
                simpleObjectModel = Model.of(new SimpleObject());
               
                initialize();
 
                add(form);
        }
 
 
        private void initialize() {
                CompoundPropertyModel model = new CompoundPropertyModel(simpleObjectModel);
                form.setModel(model);
               
                form.add(createAddresssesChoice());
                form.add(createAddToListButton());
                form.add(createRemoveFromListButton());
                form.add(createNotificationList());
        }
 
        private ListMultipleChoice<String> createAddresssesChoice() {
                return new ListMultipleChoice<String>("addresses", selectedAddresses, List.of("adress1", "address2"));
        }
 
        private AjaxButton createRemoveFromListButton() {
                return new AjaxButton("removeFromList") {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                       
                        @Override
                        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                                SimpleObject simpleObject = simpleObjectModel.getObject();
                                List<String> notifications = selectedNotifications.getObject();
                                if(simpleObject != null && notifications != null) {
                                        notifications.stream()
                                                .forEach(address -> simpleObject.removeAddress(address));
                                        target.add(SimpleTestPanel.this.form);
                                }
                        }
                };
        }
 
        private AjaxButton createAddToListButton() {
                return new AjaxButton("addToList") {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                       
                        @Override
                        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                                SimpleObject simpleObject = simpleObjectModel.getObject();
                                List<String> addresses = selectedAddresses.getObject();
                                if(simpleObject != null && addresses != null) {
                                        addresses.stream()
                                                .forEach(address -> simpleObject.addAddress(address));
                                        target.add(SimpleTestPanel.this.form);
                                }
                        }
                };
        }
        private ListMultipleChoice<String> createNotificationList() {
                return new ListMultipleChoice<String>("notifications", selectedNotifications, simpleObjectModel.getObject().getAddresses());
        }
}
```